# BatchSize is not working in SpaceIterator in Gigaspace

Tags: java, spring, gigaspaces

SpaceIterator always returning the whole results even if we specify the batchSize. How to get the results 500 records for each request.

```
SpaceDocument sampleSpaceDoc = new SpaceDocument("space_doc");

SpaceIterator<SpaceDocument> iterator =
gigaSpace.iterator(sampleSpaceDoc, new SpaceIteratorConfiguration().setBatchSize(500).setIteratorType(SpaceIteratorType.CURSOR).setReadModifiers(ReadModifiers.DIRTY_READ).setMaxInactiveDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(5)));
```

In above code, even if we set the `batchSize`, its always returning whole results set not first 500 records.
It would be great any pointers or suggestions to proceed further.

Comment: `BatchSize` only limits the results retrieving from the server. When iterating it will still fetch all the results but in batches of 500 (or less).

Comment: Yes you are correct .  I try to implement pagination concept using the Space Iterator. When i iterate and collect, its giving all the results. I have referred this URL [https://docs.gigaspaces.com/dev-java/query-paging-support.html ]. Is there any other way to implement pagination for space records(around 1 lakh records)?